# RestFB doesn't fetch posts from certain account for certain keywords?

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

We are trying to fetch posts which have 2 keywords (e.g. Chicago Sports) via the RestFB query interface.
Its able to fetch posts from a certain account, but for some weird reason it skips the messages from a different account even though both of the messages have been marked as Public.

What could be the reason that its unable to fetch data from a certain account. Note: I am using account1's credentials to perform a search and the posts are present in account2, account3.

```
Connection<Post> messages = fbClient.fetchConnection("search",
        Post.class,
            Parameter.with("q", keyword),
            Parameter.with("limit", limit),
            Parameter.with("type", "post"));
```

Appreciate your help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Does the Graph API Explorer tool (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) return the correct results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon the comments above, and with both search request via an SDK as well as the search request via the Explorer tool not returning public results, I would say you have a bug you should log at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs (you have to perform a search before Facebook "displays" the create bug button) and report back here with a link to the defect.

Comment: Message: If you're going to do a presentation please be loud and enthusiastic, cause if not I'll make out known that I'm bored.

I posted the above message to account1, account2 and account3 using their respective FB credentials.

When I searched for the above messages using keywords bored enthusiastic, I only get messages(http://pastie.org/3539861) from account1 (Amirtha Priya) and account2 (Eon Dispy) via the Graph API Explorer tool. I am unable to fetch post from account3 (Valarmathi Arikrishnan).

Comment: Yep, still sounds like a good bug to log at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.  Please report back here with a link to your defect.